# Force www. in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm normally used to using .htaccess files to force a domain to use www. (i.e. http://www.example.com instead of http://example.com):

```
#Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

Redirect permanent "www.example.com" "http://www.example.com"
Redirect permanent "example.com" "http://www.example.com"
```

However this doesn't work in a rails app. What is the rails alternative to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
order deny,allow
```

Taken from http://www.htaccesseditor.com/en.shtml#a_WWW

**Note:** The .htaccess file should be put inside the public folder of the Rails project.

Comment: the problem is rails via passenger ignores the .htaccess file.

Comment: no it works, put it inside the public folder of your Rails project

Comment: ah I had to turn on mod_rewrite for that domain but now seems to be working correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a newer Rails version, an alternative to using Apaches mod_rewrite would be using the [Canonical Host Rack middleware](http://coderack.org/users/tylerhunt/entries/6-canonical-host).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with Metal

```
./script/generate metal www_redirect
```

And then in app/metal/www_redirect.rb

```
# Allow the metal piece to run in isolation
require(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../config/environment") unless defined?(Rails)

class WwwRedirect
  def self.call(env)
    if env["SERVER_NAME"] !~ /^www\./
      [302, {"Content-Type" => "text/html", "Location" => "http://www.#{env["HTTP_HOST"]}#{env["REQUEST_PATH"]}"}, ["Redirecting..."]]
    else
      [404, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["Not Found"]]
    end
  end
end
```